# Can no longer run any node packages after reinstall

Tags: node.js, npm

My node suddenly stopped working so I removed everything and installed node with homebrew.

Now I cant install grunt, nodemon, bower etc.

```
Pers-MacBook-Air:backendMD perstrom$ sudo npm install -g grunt-cli
Password:
/Users/perstrom/.node/bin/grunt -> /Users/perstrom/.node/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt
grunt-cli@0.1.13 /Users/perstrom/.node/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli
├── resolve@0.3.1
├── nopt@1.0.10 (abbrev@1.0.5)
└── findup-sync@0.1.3 (lodash@2.4.1, glob@3.2.11)
Pers-MacBook-Air:backendMD perstrom$ grunt --version
bash: grunt: command not found
Pers-MacBook-Air:backendMD perstrom$
```

What can be wrong? How do I debug this?

Comment: did you try restarting terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to expend your path (make sure this folder contains the bins):

```
export PATH=/Users/perstrom/.node/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Thx! Struggling several hours with this.